# Hylafax doesn't answer

Tags: debian, modem, fax

First, the configuration :

OS : Linux Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u6 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Hylafax 6.0.6

Modem : USR 56k model 5630 (RS232) set on ttyS0

I think my settings are quite good, when I test my modem, it reply me with all AT commands.
I can send fax without any problem
But, because there's a "but", I can't receive.
On the fax sender, dial tone is like my server didn't reply
On the fax server, I receive this log :

```
Jan 19 08:31:02.37: [ 4549]: SESSION BEGIN 000000044 33153566683 <= fax server phone number

Jan 19 08:31:02.37: [ 4549]: HylaFAX (tm) Version 6.0.6

Jan 19 08:31:02.37: [ 4549]: <-- [13:AT+FCLASS=1A\r]

Jan 19 08:31:02.39: [ 4549]: --> [5:ERROR]

Jan 19 08:31:02.39: [ 4549]: ANSWER: Ring detected without successful handshake

Jan 19 08:31:02.39: [ 4549]: Ring detected without successful handshake

Jan 19 08:31:02.39: [ 4549]: SESSION END
```

I've searched for any solution, without any success.
Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Issue is solved

Hylafax suggest as a default setting to set the modem as a Class 1 modem.

I've tested a setting as a Class 2.0 modem and now I can receive fax